# How to overcome the namespace evil of C++ header files?

Tags: c++, header, namespaces, typedef, using

With one of my projects I will head into the C++ field. Basically I am coming 
from a Java background and was wondering how the concept of Java packages 
is realized in the C++ world. This led me to the C++ concept of namespaces.

I am absolutely fine with namespaces so far but when it comes to header files 
things are becoming kind of inefficient with respect to fully qualified class 
names, using-directives and using-declarations.

A very good description of the issue is [this](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/migrating_to_namespaces.htm) article by Herb Sutter.

As I understand it this all boils down to: If you write a header file always 
use fully qualified type names to refer to types from other namespaces.

This is almost unacceptable. As a C++ header commonly provides the declaration 
of a class, a maximum of readability has top priority. Fully qualifying each 
type from a different namespace creates a lot of visual noise, finally 
diminishing readability of the header to a degree which raises the question 
whether to use namespaces at all.

Nevertheless I want to take advantage of C++ namespaces and so put some thought into 
the question: How to overcome the namespace evil of C++ header files? After 
some research I think typedefs could be a valid cure to this problem.

Following you will find a C++ sample program which demonstrates how I would 
like to use public class scoped typedefs to import types from other namespaces. 
The program is syntactically correct and compiles fine on MinGW W64. So far so 
good, but I am not sure whether this approach happily removes the using keyword 
from the header but brings in another problem which I am simply not aware of. 
Just something tricky like the things described by Herb Sutter.

That is I kindly ask everybody who has a thorough understanding of C++ to 
review the code below and let me know whether this should work or not. Thanks 
for your thoughts.

**MyFirstClass.hpp**

```
#ifndef MYFIRSTCLASS_HPP_
#define MYFIRSTCLASS_HPP_

namespace com {
namespace company {
namespace package1 {

class MyFirstClass
{
public:
    MyFirstClass();
    ~MyFirstClass();

private:

};

} // namespace package1
} // namespace company
} // namespace com

#endif /* MYFIRSTCLASS_HPP_ */
```

**MyFirstClass.cpp**

```
#include "MyFirstClass.hpp"

using com::company::package1::MyFirstClass;

MyFirstClass::MyFirstClass()
{
}

MyFirstClass::~MyFirstClass()
{
}
```

**MySecondClass.hpp**

```
#ifndef MYSECONDCLASS_HPP_
#define MYSECONDCLASS_HPP_

#include <string>
#include "MyFirstClass.hpp"

namespace com {
namespace company {
namespace package2 {

    /*
     * Do not write using-declarations in header files according to
     * Herb Sutter's Namespace Rule #2.
     *
     * using std::string; // bad
     * using com::company::package1::MyFirstClass; // bad
     */

class MySecondClass{

public:
    /*
     * Public class-scoped typedefs instead of using-declarations in
     * namespace package2. Consequently we can avoid fully qualified
     * type names in the remainder of the class declaration. This
     * yields maximum readability and shows cleanly the types imported
     * from other namespaces.
     */
    typedef std::string String;
    typedef com::company::package1::MyFirstClass MyFirstClass;

    MySecondClass();
    ~MySecondClass();

    String getText() const; // no std::string required
    void setText(String as_text); // no std::string required

    void setMyFirstInstance(MyFirstClass anv_instance); // no com::company:: ...
    MyFirstClass getMyFirstInstance() const; // no com::company:: ...

private:
    String is_text; // no std::string required
    MyFirstClass inv_myFirstInstance; // no com::company:: ...
};

} // namespace package2
} // namespace company
} // namespace com

#endif /* MYSECONDCLASS_HPP_ */
```

**MySecondClass.cpp**

```
#include "MySecondClass.hpp"

/*
 * According to Herb Sutter's "A Good Long-Term Solution" it is fine
 * to write using declarations in a translation unit, as long as they
 * appear after all #includes.
 */
using com::company::package2::MySecondClass; // OK because in cpp file and
                                             // no more #includes following
MySecondClass::MySecondClass()
{
}

MySecondClass::~MySecondClass()
{
}

/*
 * As we have already imported all types through the class scoped typedefs
 * in our header file, we are now able to simply reuse the typedef types
 * in the translation unit as well. This pattern shortens all type names
 * down to a maximum of "ClassName::TypedefTypeName" in the translation unit -
 * e.g. below we can simply write "MySecondClass::String". At the same time the
 * class declaration in the header file now governs all type imports from other
 * namespaces which again enforces the DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself - principle.
 */

// Simply reuse typedefs from MySecondClass
MySecondClass::String MySecondClass::getText() const
{
    return this->is_text;
}

// Simply reuse typedefs from MySecondClass
void MySecondClass::setText(String as_text)
{
    this->is_text = as_text;
}

// Simply reuse typedefs from MySecondClass
void MySecondClass::setMyFirstInstance(MyFirstClass anv_instance)
{
    this->inv_myFirstInstance = anv_instance;
}

// Simply reuse typedefs from MySecondClass
MySecondClass::MyFirstClass MySecondClass::getMyFirstInstance() const
{
    return this->inv_myFirstInstance;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "MySecondClass.hpp"

using com::company::package2::MySecondClass; // OK because in cpp file and
                                             // no more #includes following
int main()
{
    // Again MySecondClass provides all types which are imported from
    // other namespaces and are part of its interface through public
    // class scoped typedefs
    MySecondClass *lpnv_mySecCls = new MySecondClass();

    // Again simply reuse typedefs from MySecondClass
    MySecondClass::String ls_text = "Hello World!";
    MySecondClass::MyFirstClass *lpnv_myFirClsf =
            new MySecondClass::MyFirstClass();

    lpnv_mySecCls->setMyFirstInstance(*lpnv_myFirClsf);

    lpnv_mySecCls->setText(ls_text);
    printf("Greetings: %s\n", lpnv_mySecCls->getText().c_str());

    lpnv_mySecCls->setText("Goodbye World!");
    printf("Greetings: %s\n", lpnv_mySecCls->getText().c_str());

    getchar();

    delete lpnv_myFirClsf;
    delete lpnv_mySecCls;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a question. Maybe you should post to code review?

Comment: Use fully qualified names and don't create Java-like namespace names. Don't use `new`. Welcome to C++.

Comment: This will be least of your worries in C++, just give it some time

Comment: just don't use so many levels of namespace, I've rarely seen an actual need beyond one level. the `com::company` part is especially meaningless.

Comment: Forget what you know about Java. Don't nest namespaces so much. Don't use `new` when you don't need it (the example code does not need it). Trying to write C++ as if it was Java will not produce good results. Don't pretend the languages are similar, because they are not.

Comment: I find std::string much faster to type and easier to read than MySecondClass::String. Concerning your code, the excessive use of empty namespaces nests is a problem. Just call it package1, drop the whole company stuff. Lastly, a typical Java error: If you're using new in C++ to achieve the same as in Java, you're doing something wrong. Good luck!

Comment: Also, avoid hungarian notation. That's for C++BC. ;)

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Class-level typedefs are ok. Namespace-level are not. The OP is doing something acceptable in his code.

Comment: @Macke oh you're right, misread it due to indentation failure, however it's still kind of useless and not helpful/slightly harmful.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Yeah. Typedef:ing std::string is pointless and obfuscating. Typedeffing template classes and containers is something I find useful though

Comment: People used to C++ often find fully qualified names *easier* to read, as you don't have to guess what namespace is active.

Comment: @KillianDS Think of managed C++ with namespaces like System::Runtime::InteropServices. There **are** needs for several namespace levels, whether it's Java, C++ or any language. The fact is header files are a problem when using namespaces and there is no clean way around it. Why do you think no languages created in the last two decades use header files?

Comment: @user1610015: .NET doing it doesn't make it necessary, elegant or modern. Most C++ code well lives without it.

Comment: I would recommend avoiding `using` directives both in the header and the implementation files. In particular a using directive to pull the elements for which you are going to provide the definition will get you into trouble.

Comment: @user1610015 The problem with header files has nothing to do with namespaces. namespaces in C++ are not .Net modules, so there's no need for the same nesting as with modules.

Comment: @user1610015: That is just one design decision because they wanted to maintain the same hierarchy that is available in other .NET languages. There is nothing inhibiting the user of `SystemRT` instead of `System::Runtime` (consider `crt` is a well known short hand for C runtime) or even `SysRTInterop` for the whole thing. I don't recall any place where I have used more than two nested namespaces (and in some places the external one was the company/group name)

Comment: @bames53 The problem of header files with namespaces is that, as described in the question, you shouldn't use **using** declarations in headers because then the names are exported to the global scope of whoever includes the header, thereby defeating the purpose of namespaces. So you're left with the need to fully qualify all names, even if they're in a really long namespace.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I'm not sure what you mean. .NET is language-independent, but the namespace hierarchy is the same in any language that supports .NET.

Comment: @user1610015: Exactly, the hierarchy in C++ was not designed for C++, it was adopted from the .NET framework. An equivalent framework designed for C++ would have followed different conventions and would probably have `SystemRT` or `SysRTInterop` rather than the lenghty `System::Runtime::InteropServices`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pain is mitigated by reducing complexity. You're bending C++ into Java. (That works just as bad as trying the other way.)

Some hints:

- Remove  the "com" namespace level. (This is just a java-ism that you don't need)
- Drop the "company" namespace, maybe replace by "product" or "library" namespace (i.e. boost, Qt, OSG, etc). Just pick something that's unique w.r.t. the other libs you're using.
- You don't need to fully declare names that are in the same namespace you're in (caveat emptor: template classe, see comment). Just avoid any `using namespace` directives in the headers. (And use with care in C++ files, if at all. Inside functions is preferred.)
- Consider namespace aliases (in functions/cpp files), i.e `namespace bll = boost::lambda;`. This creates shortcuts that are quite neat.
- Also, by hiding private members/types using the [pimpl](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/) pattern, your header have less types to expose.

P.S: Thanks to @KillianDS a few good tips in comments (that were deleted when I edited them into the question.)

Comment: @Macke I would insist on avoiding the `using namespace` directive. This behaviour helps against name collision. Otherwise namespaces become less powerful. (I use `using namespace` only in cpp files where it has an added value)

Comment: @StephaneRolland: I thought that was what I wrote?

Comment: the first time I read (maybe before the edits) it was not stressed enough. Maybe it's just me :-). That's why I used the word **insist**.

Comment: "*You don't need to fully declare names that are in the same namespace you're in.*" You do if you're writing a template – ADL can cause ambiguities where you least expect them.

Comment: @Macke Thanks a lot. I think the message is clear: As simple as possible.